# React save temporary file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, serverside-javascript

I have a base64 data in my react frontend, and I want to convert this to a img file (png, jpeg,etc) and save it to server side temporary folder (call it tmp).

Ultimately, I want to generate a url www.mywebsite.com/tmp/myImage.png, which I want to pass it into Opengraph meta tag.

I've tried using libraries such as [tmp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tmp) and [base64-img](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-img) but I cannot use them in my react front end components.

How would I call a server side function from my react front end?

What would be the best way to convert base64 data to a image file and save it in my server.

Comment: Post the data from the client to your server and use one of the libraries you have linked to convert it to an image on the server.

Comment: @James and would i use express to do that?

Comment: doesn't _have_ to be Express, particularly if this is the only endpoint you'd expect to have. I'd use the [built-in HTTP support](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/)

Answer (score 1):

On your backend, it's pretty simple to save to file:

```
// where "yourBase64Data" is the incoming base64 image from the POST request.
let imagePath = 'yourPath/tmp/yourImage.jpg';
require("fs").writeFile(imagePath, yourBase64Data, 'base64', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

Then in your frontend, when you retrieve it, you can decode and display it like this:

```
let base64Image = “iVBORw0KGggANSbCAIAA...”;

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64Image;

document.body.appendChild(img);
```